# Delphi alternatives to some File I/O C++ lib functions?

Tags: c++, delphi, io

- fopen_s <--> OpenFile
- fclose <--> CloseFile

Is my assumption correct?

I wonder what is better to use, OpenFile or CreateFile. The latter gives more freedom, but is it faster?

Comment: Can you specify your problem? Yes, these functions (c++ and their delphi equivalents) do similar things; the performance depends on the problem you solve, they translate to the corresponding winapi system calls, their (OpenFile, CreateFile) behaviour is different.

Comment: I am afraid @vissi is wrong. See my answer below.

Comment: You mean, delphi streams are more suitable? Yes, but they resemble c++ streams (`<fstream>`), not c-style structs, and winapi-style calls can also be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use neither in Delphi – I would use streams. Low level file handling is messy and error-prone, it's much better to use higher level routines if you can.

You ask which is faster, `OpenFile` or `CreateFile`. They are basically the same, but any method of opening a file is going to map onto the system call anyway so the performance will be the same no matter how you do it. What's more, when does performance for opening a file matter, it's when reading or writing that time is expended.

Any questions about performance are hard to answer without context. The answer for an app which reads thousands of small text files is different from one which streams backups to a tape drive, for example.

Anyway, to stress my original point, take advantage of the excellent high-level framework that Delphi provides, use streams, avoid low-level I/O and enjoy!

---

So, how does one use a Delphi stream? I'll try to illustrate this with a made up example of writing some text, in a string, to a file.

```
procedure SaveTextToFile(FileName, Text: string);
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate);
  Try
    if Length(Text)>0 then
      Stream.WriteBuffer(Text[1], Length(Text)*SizeOf(Char));
  Finally
    Stream.Free;
  End;
end;
```

It's pretty self-explanatory. The second parameter to the TFileStream constructor determines the file mode. Here we want to create a brand new file and so if any contents exist, they are removed. You can also specify file sharing with this parameter.

The code to write the buffer out has a little boiler-plate but again is very simple.

Loading it back results in an almost identical routine:

```
function LoadTextFromFile(FileName: string): string;
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead);
  Try
    SetLength(Result, Stream.Size div SizeOf(Char));
    if Length(Result)>0 then
      Stream.ReadBuffer(Result[1], Length(Result)*SizeOf(Char));
  Finally
    Stream.Free;
  End;
end;
```

If you wish to seek around the file then you can set the `Position` property of the stream, or call the `Seek()` method. The advantage of the latter is that you can seek from current position or end position.

Streams are idiomatic Delphi. They are used pervasively in the RTL and VCL and by 3rd party libraries. They signal errors with exceptions in the native Delphi manner. There are many different stream classes that all derive from a common ancestor and many routines accept this common ancestor.

Comment: And of course you are aware of the fact that *both* `OpenFile` 
*and* `CreateFile` are functions of the Windows API?

Comment: Exactly. Better question than "what is the closest function to this procedural non-OOP function I know right now", ask the question "what is idiomatic, up to date, and the right way to use the Delphi RTL, and if classes provided", and use Stream classes rather than handle based procedural APIs.

Comment: Thank you. Not that I don't know how to use a stream, but wanted to learn about memory mapped files instead. Never seen such. Anyway, I used streams.

Comment: @pop32 Memory mapped files: [Managing Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx). The examples are in C but they translate readily to Delphi. I'd look at wrapping up the system API calls in a class to abstract away the nitty-gritty. I'd be amazed if there wasn't such a class in existence and available for public consumption.

Answer (score 3):

Low-level Delphi file handling is done like this:

```
procedure Proc;
var
  f: file; // or f: TextFile;
begin
  FileMode := fmOpenRead; // or fmOpenWrite or fmOpenReadWrite
  AssignFile(f, 'C:\file.txt');
  try
    // Reset/Rewrite
    // A number of BlockRead/BlockWrite/ReadLn/WriteLn...
  finally
    CloseFile(f);
  end;
end;
```

This is the classic way of working with files in Delphi, and this is what corresponds to the C++ functions.

`OpenFile` and `CreateFile` are *not* Delphi functions, so they cannot correspond to the C++ functions. Instead, these are functions of the Windows API, which is available in *all* (Windows) programming languages. The former, [`OpenFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365430(VS.85).aspx), is not recommended. Use [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) instead. But if you use the Windows API file-handling functions to open/create a file, you should also use these to read/write the file, e.g. the [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467(VS.85).aspx) function, and you must finish by using the [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211(VS.85).aspx) function.

Notice in particular that `OpenFile` is a function of the Windows API, whereas `CloseFile` is a Delphi RTL function, so you cannot even use these together! Delphi: `AssignFile`->`CloseFile`; Windows API: `CreateFile`->`CloseHandle`.

You should also know, that there are *high-level* functions for managing files in the Delphi RTL (run-time library). I am sure other users will promote these.

Comment: Better to say it is a 'Pascal' way to work with files, not 'classic'. It is appropriate in console applications, but should be avoided in VCL applications.

Comment: @Serg: Let's not argue about the low-level/high-level thing, but I don't see why the GUI/console distinction should have anything to do with how you read/write to files?

Comment: It should be avoided even in console applications.

Comment: Ok, here's my case: There is 2GB file (similar to archive, but no compression, just files inside) that I have to read from all the time the app is running to read file data that is needed(not all is needed). The C++ app uses file_seek. What should I use for best, I meant fastest, performance?

Comment: yes, there's a cache(1..500) I store the file that is read by the app. But if it's not in the cache, it has to read it. The C++ app uses file_seek, but it opens the file only once(on class constructor).

Comment: @pop32 What's wrong with a TFileStream? I can't help feeling that you've accepted the wrong answer. This legacy Pascal file access stuff is plain weird, deprecated, doesn't support huge files. This is trivial for `TFileStream` and loads easier to work with and idomatic Delphi. No sane individual writes new code like this nowadays, and hasn't done so this century.

Comment: @pop32 Memory mapped files are generally the fastest because the system can map the system file cache into your process so there's no need to perform memory copies. But the vast majority of applications get admirable performance with a standard Win32 file I/O. And in Delphi the easy way to do Win32 file I/O is with a stream.

Comment: Can you show me a sample with memory mapping? I never used that. I'd take your answer

Comment: @pop32 I doubt you need memory maps. They are pretty advanced. You would be better advised to use standard system file I/O, via a TFileStream, and only consider memory mapping if you ran into performance limitations. But really, do absolutely anything other than ghastly Pascal I/O like Andreas says. I've got a lot of time for Andreas but I can't fathom his fascination with this abomination.

Comment: @pop32 And I'm really not interested in who has the green tick. What I'm more concerned about is giving you good advice.

Comment: @pop32 I've updated my answer to include a very simple example of stream usage.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long while since I have done any Delphi programming, but I remember that file IO were much better served using TStream suite of classes (TFileStream for file IO). They are essentially the equivalent mechanism of C++'s IO streams library, which is, of course, the preferred way of doing file IO in C++. See [this simple example](http://www.latiumsoftware.com/en/delphi/00001.php) and this [wiki](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/TFileStream_Class).

Comment: @ANdreas. Sort of. You mention they exist. David actually names them.