# Delphi File Access - Why do I get an incomplete output if I don't close my file?

Tags: delphi, text-files

Following is a simple console application then generates ten sets of 3 random numbers and prints them out to both the console window and a text file, 'Output.txt'.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;
var
  outputFile: TextFile;
  i: Integer;
  a,b,c: Single;
begin
  try
    Randomize;
    AssignFile(outputFile, 'Output.txt');
    ReWrite(outputFile);
    for i := 0 to 9 do
    begin
      a := Random;
      b := Random;
      c := Random;
      WriteLn(FloatToStr(a) + Char(9) + FloatToStr(b) + Char(9) + FloatToStr(c));
      WriteLn(outputFile, FloatToStr(a) + Char(9) + FloatToStr(b) + Char(9) + FloatToStr(c));
    end;
    Close(outputFile);
    Sleep(10000);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

The text file holds the same information as the console window only if I include line 26:

> Close(outputFile);

If I omit this from the code I would expect to get the same data printed to the text file anyway but what is actually printed in the text file is the same for the first 9 lines and then an incomplete final line.

Why does this happen? By what process does the final line only get written in part due to the omission of the Close procedure?

Comment: Please don't use ancient legacy Pascal I/O for new code. Use modern methods to stream text.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I was unaware of Delphi File Streams until now. For the benefit of others, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328594/delphi-alternatives-to-some-file-i-o-c-lib-functions) is a link in which you elaborate on how to do this.

Comment: That's not a great reference for your needs. You are looking for `TStreamWriter`.

Comment: @Trojanian - another useful approaches would be 1) TStringList/TJclStringList/TJclWideStrings - when you need to read small or medium text file to memory and then parse it. and 2) memory-mapped files, when they are big. Google about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is caused because the file output is buffered. When you close the file it causes the buffer to be flushed and the remaining content put out to disk.

An alternative is to perform a `Flush(outputFile)` after the `WriteLn` for the file, it will accomplish the same thing, but at the expense of performance.

Comment: The implied alternate behavior is that when the file isn't properly closed, the write buffer isn't flushed, which is why some data is missing.  Also, caching is a good thing -- repeated calls to `Flush` is a fast way to kill performance.

Comment: @afrazier I put an addendum at the end of the alternative adding that it impacts performance

Comment: True that! It certainly is weird.

Comment: The RTL does not get a chance to close/flush files on program exit. The Operating System starts unloading the program, including the RTL, as soon as it gets an application-close instruction. Once that starts to happen, everthing becomes very fragile and stops working correctly: it's too late to try to flush open files.